# Draw a structure for each of the following isomers of unsaturated amine 1

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

My ochem professor has several practice exams as resources but does not include answers,  I believe I understand the concepts but once I apply them I'm not sure whether I'm right or clueless. Can anyone check my work and if I'm wrong tell me why ?

> The format of his exams does not seem to be anywhere else online but if it is can someone provide a link. I really want to understand how to deal with these more complex structures rather than look at Fischer projections and simple problems again

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggp3l.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjF5e.jpg]

Comment: Are you sure that the 2-amino-4-methylhexanoic acid at the bottom left of the page is the enantiomer of the given (2S,4R)-2-amino-4-methylhexanoic acid **1**?